# After Upgrading from D7 to D8, D8 does not look like D7 at all

Tags: migrations

I have successfully performed a D7 -> D8 migration of my company site. Everything seemed to go well, but when I'm accessing the Drupal 8 site, the entire design is pretty much gone.

How can I get the old design back again for Drupal 8?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drupal 8 is very different from Drupal 7, same goes with previous major versions of Drupal.

This means that themes and modules can only work for a single Drupal major version (fx 6, 7 or 8).

When you migrate a site from D7 to D8 you have to re-implement the theme. In Drupal 8 we now use Twig as the template language so you pretty much have to start from scratch (unlike 5 -> 6 -> 7 where the theme differences wasn't that big and a lot could be reused).

Comment: If the changes are that major, it seems like this should be emphasized on the project's official web site. Given that lots of people have probably come to expect that the changes are relatively minor (based on the migration path between previous versions), something like this would break a lot of peoples' expectations, potentially leading to much grief.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Maybe, but that's up to the association :) In many ways Drupal 8 is a new system compare to Drupal 6 and 7.